# Adding a new GeoProjection?

Tags: geography, geographics

The documentation for `GeoProjectionData` gives a list of supported `GeoProjections`. I was not able to find any documentation on how to add a new `GeoProjection`. I have a spec for a new one in the form of equations for $x$ and $y$ as functions of lat and long, and I'd like to take advantage of Mathematica's `GeoGraphics` to display that new projection with world data.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious?